# Why isn't my reactive expression filtering data?

Tags: r, shiny

I am in the beginning of developing a shiny app that will automate data processing from a lab instrument. I am trying to filter the data multiple times down the line to create multiple independent outputs from the same reactive file upload. I know you can't modify reactives directly, so I start the reactive by storing it as a new object (any advice on doing this multiple times for different outputs is also appreciated)

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(formattable)
library(tidyverse)

#Module File Input UI Function
csvFileInput <- function(id, label = "CSV File"){
  fileInput(NS(id, "upload"), label, accept = ".csv", buttonLabel = "Select File")
}

#Module File Input Server Function
csvFileServer <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    userFile <- reactive({
      req(input$upload)
      input$upload
    })
    
    dataframe <- reactive({
      read.csv(userFile()$datapath, header = TRUE)
    })
    
    return(dataframe)
  })
}

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Lachat Run Analyzer"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      csvFileInput("lachat_file")
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      
      dataTableOutput("table"),
      
    )
  )

)

# Define server logic required to analyze data and generate screening table
server <- function(input, output) {
  df_nutrient <- csvFileServer("lachat_file")
   
  nutrient_output <- reactive({
    
    nutrient = df_nutrient()
    
    nutrient$Sample.ID <- as.factor(nutrient$Sample.ID)
    nutrient$Analyte.Name <- as.factor(nutrient$Analyte.Name)
    nutrient$Detection.Date <- as.factor(nutrient$Detection.Date)
    nutrient$Concentration.Units <- as.factor(nutrient$Concentration.Units)
    
    nutrient %>% filter(Sample.Type == "Check Standard")
    
    nutrient
  })

output$table <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(nutrient_output())
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I go to filter the data, however, it does not work and I still have all rows in the dataTableOutput (54 rows is the entire csv):
[image: dataTableOutput]

Comment: I can't test since no data was provided. With that said, in your `nutrient_output` reactive, you're not saving the filtered data. So it first outputs the filtered data but then returns the original data. I would remove the last line `nutrient` from the reactive.

Comment: This was the issue... Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be here:

```
nutrient %>% filter(Sample.Type == "Check Standard")

nutrient
```

The filtered value is not stored anywhere.
consider this revision:

```
filterd_tbl <- nutrient %>% filter(Sample.Type == "Check Standard")

return(filterd_tbl)
```